# GAE Task Queue Payloads serialisation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My question is, when does serialisation of tasks happen, especially if I use addAsync?

If I have this task:

```
class MyTask implements DeferredTask {
   private String payload;
   public void enqueue(String payload) {
      this.payload = payload;
      QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().addAsync(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(this));
   }

   public void run() {
      Logger.get("foo").info(payload);
   }
}
```

is it valid to do

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.enqueue("bar1");
task.enqueue("bar2");
```

can it then happen that there is no task with "bar1" as payload?

Comment: It;s possible that a queued task may be run multiple times, so any task needs to be idempotent.  It's pretty much impossible to garuntee that a task won't be run twice (though it's not normal behaviour), all you can do is deal with the possibility in your code.

Comment: what if I give it a unique task name? normaly that would throw a ThombStonedException afaik.

but, my question was acutaly about serialisation. so ist there one task with payload "bar1" and one with "bar2" that gets executed (maybe multiple times). or can it happen that there is no task wit "bar1" in the excample above?

Comment: You would always get a task with the "bar1" payload, unless there was a failure when you submit the task, which is possible.  The serialization of the payload is performed on the client side, and submitted with the task request.  The payload size is also limited.

Comment: A unique task name will prevent another task from being scheduled with the same name "for a period of time" however that doesn't mean the task won't retry in the event of a failure. Form the docs `Note that task names do not provide an absolute guarantee of once-only semantics. In rare cases, multiple calls to create a task of the same name may succeed. It's also possible in exceptional cases for a task to run more than once—even if it was only created once.`